# Username:Password vs sftp.site.com

Tags: authentication, winscp

I'm having issues with using the following format [using WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#hostkey)

```
open sftp://user:password@site.com
```

vs. this, which works with the console and GUI:

```
open sftp.site.com.
```

I would like to automate logging in through the command line but when I try with sftp://user:password@site.com I get a timeout.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine for me both ways.  Is the problem that you are using `site.com` instead of `sftp.site.com` in your first example?

Just because you specify the protocol sftp, doesn't mean it will attempt to connect to `sftp.site.com` when you provide `site.com` as the host.  You still need the full hostname, the `sftp://` just tells it what protocol you want to speak once connected.